# Decompile Error C# CallSite

Tags: c#, dotpeek

When I decompile a mvc web api with Dotpeek, I have some error.
This is decompiled code:

```
    public class SignalRNotifier : INotifier
  {
    private readonly IHubContext DashboardHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Dashboard>();

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DiscussionCreated(Delecs.Sapco.MinutesOfMeeting.Libs.DTO.Discussion.CreatedModel discussion, string[] users)
    {
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      if (SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1 == null)
      {
        // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
        SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof (System.Threading.Tasks.Task), typeof (SignalRNotifier)));
      }
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      Func<CallSite, object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> func = SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1.Target;
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>> callSite = SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1;
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      if (SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__0 == null)
      {
        // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
        SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__0 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, Delecs.Sapco.MinutesOfMeeting.Libs.DTO.Discussion.CreatedModel, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "onDiscussionCreated", (IEnumerable<Type>) null, typeof (SignalRNotifier), (IEnumerable<CSharpArgumentInfo>) new CSharpArgumentInfo[2]
        {
          CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, (string) null),
          CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, (string) null)
        }));
      }
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated field
      object obj = SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__0.Target((CallSite) SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__0, this.DashboardHub.Clients.Users((IList<string>) users), discussion);
      return func((CallSite) callSite, obj);
    }
}
```

I know solution is rename by hand,but i don't khow how to fix this line :

```
SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(System.Threading.Tasks.Task), typeof(SignalRNotifier)));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompiling .net assembly with dotPeek gives invalid syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405892/decompiling-net-assembly-with-dotpeek-gives-invalid-syntax)

Comment: @SirRufo tnx but my question is diffrent.

Comment: What makes you feel so? Different \uXXXX code? Trust me, it is the same reason and the same solution (rename by hand)

Comment: @SirRufo I know solution is rename by hand,but i don't khow how to fix this line :

 SignalRNotifier.\u003C\u003Eo__2.\u003C\u003Ep__1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(System.Threading.Tasks.Task), typeof(SignalRNotifier)));

Comment: Did you post the **whole** code for SignalRNotifier class?

Comment: yes,now post edited